# sendmail and php mail() - "no recipients found"

Tags: php, sendmail

I have installed `sendmail` on my Apache server (Ubuntu)

Everything seems to work find except an email is not beeing sent while using php `mail();`

I get an error on the Apache errorlog saying:

> /usr/sbin/sendmail: no recipients found

This is the way I'm using the function:

```
$user_email = "myemail@gmail.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $user_email . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Mydomain <do-not-reply@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

  mail($user_email,"subject","message",$headers);
```

Answer (score 4):

`$user_email = myemail@gmail.com`

should be

`$user_email = "myemail@gmail.com";`

Comment: sorry it was a mistake when i posted the question , $user_email = myemail@gmail.com would have thrown an PHP error , the real code is of course $user_email = "myemail@gmail.com";

Comment: i believe that the problem is somewhere in the Apache/php installation on the server and not code related

Answer (score 2):

What caused the error is that you had *(in your original posted code):*

`$user_email = myemail@gmail.com`

Both encompassing quotation marks and ending semi-colon were not present.

Here is the *correct* and proper form:

```
$user_email = "myemail@gmail.com";
```

It can also be written like this, using single quotes:

```
$user_email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
```

As taken from the `mail()` function on PHP.net

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 2):

I installed ssmtp on my ubuntu/apache2/php set up, and I found I had to set the sendmail parameters in php.ini

mail.force_extra_parameters = -t

As I understand it, ssmtp emulates a sendmail set up, and the -t parameter forces the mta to scan the incoming mail (from PHP) for a 'To:' header.

As a point of note, I also had to change the symbolic link that the ssmtp install created to include the full path of the bin (ln -s /usr/sbin/ssmtp sendmail), so that the file could be found by apache